# "Algebraic" closure of hyperfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

It is very interesting to see that the notion of field (single-valued addition and multiplication) can be extended to the notion of hyperfield (multi-valued addition and single-valued multiplication).

My question: Can you extend the notion of algebraic closure to a hyperfield and what is known ?